# new Audio() not Implemented in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, setattribute

I am trying to play an array of mp3 sound. I have an audio file in my html and get it using `document.CreateElement()` in my JavaScript.

When I try to set the src attribute (`setAttribute("src", string)`) I get an error in IE saying "Not Implemented".

I tried using the new Audio(), I get the same error in IE, "Not Implemented". Both approaches works in Google chrome and Firefox.

Can anyone help?

```html
<audio id="audio1" >Not supported</audio>
```

```html
audioElm = document.getElementById("audio1");
audioElm.setAttribute("src", aud[count]); 
audioElm.play();
```

Comment: may you show the code?, please

Comment: HTML
 <audio id="audio1"  >Not supported</audio>

JS
audioElm = document.getElementById("audio1");
audioElm.setAttribute("src", aud[count]);
 audioElm.play();
 
This works with Chrome and FF but not for IE. when I debug It says NOT IMPLEMENTED

Comment: What is the format of the audio file? IE only supports .mp3.

Comment: MP3. and it is not working

Comment: IE supports mp3 *and* aac audio files, so it is probably not a file type issue.

Comment: What do aud[] and count contain at the time you use them?

Answer (score 8):

HTML5 Audio not playing in IE (recent versions)?

It could be a compatibility view issue (*quirks mode*)

- is your site on the compatibility view list in IE?
- or is your page embedded in an iframe?

It could be caused by running IE on a server

- IE server versions don't support audio/video (*enhanced protected mode*)

It could be caused by running IE on a Windows 8.1 Enterprise version such as "8.1 N".

- The fix for this would be installing the Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1

Also you can go to [html5test.com](http://html5test.com/) and look in the audio section at the "MP3 support".

Comment: +1 for the IE server version not supporting audio/video. That was the answer that I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a windows server and I had the same problem playing MP3 audios in internet explorer.

The only solution I found was installing the "Desktop Experience Feature" in my server.

> Start -> Search for "Server manager" -> Features -> Add features ->
>   Select "Desktop experience" -> Next and Install

Once installation is completed, you need to restart the computer and then the feature gets enabled.