# Cannot Play Audios on IE11 and Edge. Javascript Audio Object Not Implemented?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

```
var elAudio = new Audio(audioUrl);
```

This code works fine on my desktop's (Win10) Chrome, FireFox, **Edge and IE11**.
The weird thing is, the exact code does not work on Windows 10 laptops and throws an error. **Cannot play audios & videos basically on those laptops' IE11 or Edge.** Firefox and Chrome are OK.

> Tested on 3 Desktops Win10 - **OK**
>
> Tested on 2 Laptops Win10 - **Failed**

Is there some sort of configuration somewhere?

I already tried those Internet Options on IE, but no luck.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Are you in Quirck mode or something like that?

Comment: here's the first 3 lines of the page. 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

Comment: [Here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061898/new-audio-not-implemented-in-internet-explorer) from over a year ago. It also has no answers.

Comment: Try this suggestion: `Also I had to configure enable audio in IE by going to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced Tab -> Multimedia -> Play sounds`

Comment: @evolutionxbox tried that already, still not working.  I also tried this website [link](http://html5test.com/) on those laptops and it shows that **audio element is not supported**, and videos too.

Comment: anyone else encountered this?