# JavaScript - new Audio() throw "Not implemented" on Window 10 N on IE11 and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, audio, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have a web site that plays sounds using html5 `<audio>` element, and it working grate on almost all environments.
However on 2 of our QA machines this line of code throw an exception

```
new Audio();
```

The exception is `"Not implemented"`

This happen on both IE11 and on Edge on 2 machines that runs: 
1. Window 10 Pro N 
2. Window 10 Enterprise N

On Chrome on these machines it working fine.

This issue was tested on different Windows versions (7, 8, 8.1 and 10), and it works grate. According to IE support table (see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) audio element is supported from IE-9 so I don't think this is an IE issue, in addition this also not working in Edge on these machines, so I think this is an OS issue.

[image]

Comment: Media Feature Pack is only one suggestion in the other question. Have you tried the other ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [new Audio() not Implemented in Internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061898/new-audio-not-implemented-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: If you _really_ need an answer, I'd suggest putting a small bounty on the other question.

Comment: Is this experienced on multiple different computers?

Comment: This isn't a duplication, since I'm not working on windows server, in addition the solutions on that question don't solve my problem. In addition I've linked the 2nd question to my question, to show the difference between them.

Comment: I've tested this issue on a lot of machines, running Window 7, 8 and 10. And I'm always working on IE11 and it works all the time except on this 2 machines. I can't understand what is so spacial about them, and I can find any work around

Comment: Did you try creating the element like: `var audio = document.createElement("audio");`?

Comment: Are there any plugins/extensions that could ovewrite this constructor? What does `console.log(Audio)` outputs? And indeed, does createElement('audio') or even createElement('video') throw the same error? What if you pass a valid URL to this constructor?

Comment: console.log(Audio) will output "function Audio() { [native code] }" passing a url to the contractor - new Audio("....fileName.mp3") - will result to the same exception - "not implemented"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, Windows versions that ends with N or KN are editions of Windows that are missing media-related features (for example Window Media Player, Groove Music, Video, Voice Recorder, and Skype). 

In addition to these media related features Internet Explorer as well as Microsoft Edge are missing Audio and Video elements (and other media components). 

In order of adding these features back to Windows you will have to install Windows Update Pack: [Media feature pack for Windows 10 N and Windows 10 KN editions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3010081/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-and-windows-10-kn-editions).

Once you have installed this update, all should work fine.